# Python Regex and the Copyright Symbol

Tags: python, regex, text, utf-8

### edit

Funny story, I was cleaning the text before searching in it and part of my cleaning process was removing all of those symbols.  Thus the regex I was using was working just fine :) Thank you all for your help anyway!

### original

I'm trying to detect the copyright symbol © in a UTF8 text document using python and regex.  The problem I'm having is that I have no idea how to represent the copyright symbol in regex.

I'll also be looking for TM and (R) so those would be most appreciated also, though I suspect once I have (C) it'll be simple to determine the others.

I've been valiantly searching for an answer on google but have yet to find anything that works.

If some bright spark can tell me, it would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Uh... how about `©`? Just insert the character in the regex and it should be fine. Python supports (in fact, encourages) UTF-8 encoded scripts. Then just use a unicode string (which in 3.x, is a string).

Comment: +1 to Lattyware. That's really all there is to it. (If you don't know where to find all those symbols, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102222/how-to-display-special-characters-in-python-with-print/15102300#15102300 and a half dozen other Related questions.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could convert your text to unicode and use a unicode regex pattern.

These are the three symbols you mentioned:

```
In [213]: print(u'\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN} \N{TRADE MARK SIGN} \N{REGISTERED SIGN}')
© ™ ®
```

Here is some utf-8 encoding string:

```
In [223]: content = u'\N{TRADE MARK SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')
```

Here we convert it to unicode:

```
In [224]: text = content.decode('utf-8')
```

This is a regex search for any of the three symbols:

```
In [225]: re.search(u'(\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN}|\N{TRADE MARK SIGN}|\N{REGISTERED SIGN})', text)
Out[225]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x9a1ebe0>
```

---

There are [webpages](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) [which](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) [catalog](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) every unicode character. But there are hundreds of thousands of assigned unicode code points, so it is not feasible to search for characters by browsing manually.

So, I wrote the program below to search by name for unicodes.

```
import sys
import unicodedata as ud
import re
import argparse
import functools

__usage__ = '''\
unicode_lookup.py -u '\d'    # Shows all unicode symbols that regex match '\d'
unicode_lookup.py number     # Shows all unicode symbols whose name regex matches 'number'
'''


def lookup(name_pat=None, from_num=0, to_num=0x10ffff, unicode_pattern=None,
           category_pattern=None, ignore_unnamed=True,
           combining=False):
    fmt = u"{symbol} {num} {cat} {bi} {w} {comb} {mir} '{name}'"
    print(fmt.format(
        symbol='Symbol', num='Num', name='NAME',
        cat='Category', bi='Bidirectional', w='Width',
        comb='Combining', mir='Mirrored'))
    for num in range(from_num, to_num + 1):
        s = unichr(num)
        if unicode_pattern and not unicode_pattern.match(s):
            continue
        category = ud.category(s)
        if category_pattern and not category_pattern.match(category):
            continue
        try:
            name = ud.name(s)
            if name_pat and not name_pat.search(name):
                continue
        except ValueError:
            if ignore_unnamed:
                continue
            else:
                name = '?'
        bidirectional = ud.bidirectional(s)
        combining_class = ud.combining(s)
        if combining and not combining_class:
            continue
        mirrored = ud.mirrored(s)
        width = ud.east_asian_width(s)
        data = dict(num=num, symbol=s, name=name,
                    cat=category, bi=bidirectional, w=width,
                    comb=combining_class, mir=mirrored)
        print(fmt.format(**data).encode('utf-8'))


def parse_options():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        epilog=__usage__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('name_pat',
                        type=functools.partial(re.compile, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--from_num', default=0, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--to_num', default=0x10ffff, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--unicode_pattern',
                        type=functools.partial(re.compile, flags=re.UNICODE))
    parser.add_argument('--category_pattern', type=re.compile)
    parser.add_argument('--show_unnamed', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--combining', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opt = parse_options()
    lookup(name_pat=opt.name_pat, from_num=opt.from_num, to_num=opt.to_num,
           unicode_pattern=opt.unicode_pattern,
           category_pattern=opt.category_pattern,
           ignore_unnamed=not opt.show_unnamed,
           combining=opt.combining)
```

Running

```
% unicode_lookup.py "copyright|trade|registered"
```

yields

```
Symbol Num Category Bidirectional Width Combining Mirrored 'NAME'
© 169 So ON N 0 0 'COPYRIGHT SIGN'
® 174 So ON A 0 0 'REGISTERED SIGN'
℗ 8471 So ON N 0 0 'SOUND RECORDING COPYRIGHT'
™ 8482 So ON A 0 0 'TRADE MARK SIGN'
```

Comment: Huh!  I didn't know about the `u'\N{name}' thing, that's neat.  where is a comprehensive list of the names which do and don't work in there?   [these](http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html) seem to be hit and miss ..

Comment: Nice one.  I'm stealing your script for my misc utilities folder  :D

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import re

text = 'StackOverflow® © 2013 - A great place to code™'
for m in re.finditer(r"[©®™]", text):
    print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
```

Output of this is:

```
13-14: ®
15-16: ©
45-46: ™
```