# Python - Print special characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, symbols, prettyplotlib

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102222/how-to-display-special-characters-in-python-with-print) and used it for my code. The problem is yesterday it worked and now it doesn't. As I know, I made zero change to my code.

```
fig1=plt.figure()
ax1=fig1.gca()
im1=ax1.imshow(tab_amp,cmap=cm.rainbow,extent=(0,90,-45,45),interpolation='bilinear')
ax1.set_xlabel(u'\u03b8 (°)')
ax1.set_ylabel(u'\u03c6 (°)')
cb1=fig1.colorbar(im1)
cb1.set_label(u'Amplitude de \u03b8ij (°)')
cs1 = ax1.contour(tab_amp_inv,colors='k',extent=(0,90,-45,45))
ax1.clabel(cs1, inline=1, fontsize=10,color='k')
```

It gives me this
[image]

Between yesterday an today, the only change I made to my computer is that I've installed prettyplotlib to change the default color of python. I don't know if that causes this problem?

Comment: `prettyplot` changed your default font to one that does not have that unicode character (hence why you get the box).  I would throw an issue at the prettyplot gh issue tracker.

Comment: @tcaswell do you know how to change it back manually? or just change the font of axis temporarily? I tried `rc('font',serif='Times News Roman')` but it only changed the texts inside the plot but not axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the font lacks Unicode support. You can set the font directly when setting the labels, e.g.

```
ax1.set_xlabel(u'\u03b8 (°)', fontdict={'fontname': 'Times New Roman'})
```

That should override any defaults.