# Printing special characters in Python

Tags: python, printing, character, special-characters, unique

I am a beginner Python programmer and I wanted to use this character: █. I have tried just doing: `print "█"` but I always got an error. I Have looked for solutions, but have found nothing that helped me.

Comment: So what error do you get? Is this Python 2 or 3? Is this on Windows or a different platform? In an IDE or in a terminal (or Windows console)?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569438/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display special characters in Python with print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102222/how-to-display-special-characters-in-python-with-print)

Answer (score 1):

You can print any unicode symbol by using the \uxxxx notation. For instance, 2588 is a code for unicode block.

```
 print('\u2588')
```

Comment: Oddly enough, that only works for me in Python 3, and it looks like the OP is using Python 2.

Comment: There is **way** too little context in the question to even begin to answer it.